# How can I speed this up from being rather slow

Tags: performance, delphi, tstringlist

I have the following code that I use on a form used for a mailing project.
I have a form I can call with one of the stringlists to add more contacts. That is working OK but when I 'return' from selecting contacts and call my SetupMail it takes very long time before the control on the form is actually updated with the new contactlist
Each step of the for loop takes about 1 millisecond when I time it using FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss:zzz', Now) written to a file

```
procedure TfrmMailPrepare.SetupMail;
var
  i: integer;
  MailTo: string;
  MailCc: string;
  MailBcc: string;
begin
  MailTo := '';
  MailCc := '';
  MailBcc := '';

  for i := 0 to fMailTo.Count - 1 do
    MailTo := MailTo + fMailTo.Strings[i] + '; ';
  txtMailTo.Text := MailTo;

  for i := 0 to fMailCc.Count - 1 do
    MailCc := MailCc + fMailCc.Strings[i] + '; ';
  txtMailCc.Text := MailCc;

  for i := 0 to fMailBcc.Count - 1 do
    MailBcc := MailBcc + fMailBcc.Strings[i] + '; ';
  txtMailBcc.Text := MailBcc;

  Refresh;
end;
```

Comment: Please provide a complete program, your timings, and some indication of the performance that you expect to achieve.

Comment: Your call to Refresh seems odd btw. Can't see the need for that.

Comment: The call to refresh was an experiment.

Comment: This is a classic mistake on SO. Always post the original code rather than the code you hacked around trying out ideas.

Comment: The complexity of the code makes it difficult for me to make a complete test. 
What I want is just to have the controls to show the new value as soon as they are assigned to it

Comment: Do bear in mind that we don't know any more than we can see here. We don't know the types of half of the objects. We don't know what the data is. We are blind. And especially for a perf question that makes it hard to give useful info. Let us know if you have more info to provide. If it's as simple as you say you could knock up an mcve in a few minutes.

Comment: As my application uses components that cost around $2000 total I can not be sure that even if I make a mcve it will run on another computer/compiler   
I don't recall having said that this was simple, I believe the word I used was complex  
The only unknown types in my codesample is fMailTo, fMailCc and fMailBcc and they are all TStringLists that I add items to in another codepart   
The performance issue is when writing the TStringList back to the control.

Comment: If it's as simple as the code in the question you can make an mcve. If we don't want your entire program. We want a small but complete program that exhibits the problem. You $2000 components don't matter. Or if they do, you have to tell us about them. You have got ahead of yourself. You are looking for a solution before you've identified the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing a lot of string concatenations, which means a lot of memory (re)allocations.  You can greatly simplify this code (and its overhead) by using the `TStrings.Delimiter` and `TStrings.DelimitedText` properties, eg:

```
procedure TfrmMailPrepare.SetupMail;
begin
  fMailTo.Delimiter := ';';
  txtMailTo.Text := fMailTo.DelimitedText;

  fMailCc.Delimiter := ';';
  txtMailCc.Text := fMailCc.DelimitedText;

  fMailBcc.Delimiter := ';';
  txtMailBcc.Text := fMailBcc.DelimitedText;
end;
```

If you need the whitespace after each semicolon (or the quotations that `DelimitedText` wraps each string in), you can use the `TStrings.LineBreak` and `TStrings.Text` properties instead:

```
procedure TfrmMailPrepare.SetupMail;
begin
  fMailTo.LineBreak := '; ';
  txtMailTo.Text := fMailTo.Text;

  fMailCc.LineBreak := '; ';
  txtMailCc.Text := fMailCc.Text;

  fMailBcc.LineBreak := '; ';
  txtMailBcc.Text := fMailBcc.Text;
end;
```

Comment: Do these variants perform a single allocation? I've never checked. The `Join` method might be worth mentioning too.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes, they are single-allocation operations. They pre-calculate the needed size, do the allocation, then copy characters into the allocated memory.  There is no `Join()` method in `TStrings` or `TStringList`. Maybe you are thinking of the `Join()` method in `IJclStringList` instead?

Comment: It's in `string` via the helper.

Comment: `TStringHelper.Join()` will not accept a `TStrings`/`TStringList` as input, as they do not implement the `IEnumerator<string>` or `IEnumerable<string>` interfaces.

Comment: You'd use ToStringArray which has an extra allocation for the array. And I've no idea whether Join has a good implementation. However, the code would read well, and avoid having to modify state on the list which feels wrong. Join allows us to get the result without any mutation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I would avoid `ToStringArray()` just to call `Join()`, and instead write an adapter to expose `IEnumerator<string>`/`IEnumerable<string>` for `TStrings`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  In any case, **all** of the `Join()` implementations are just looped concatenations, similar to the OP's code above. No pre-calc optimization. Also, `Join(IEnumerable<string>)` does not do anything in XE3 ([you already knew that](http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.non-tech/how-can-i-tell-if-a-bug-has-been/1087012)) and both `Join(IEnum...)` methods were [broken in XE4](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=116405).  So I have not trusted `Join()`.  If you want to avoid mutating the source `TStrings`, you could always `Assign()` to a temp `TStringList` first.

Comment: Sigh. I would have hoped that Embarcadero would have learnt by now.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau  

Your code looks a lot nicer than mine but the performance is still very slow  
I will have to investigate this a bit further since the issue is when the TStringList is written back to the control on screen - it takes about 2 sec on my computer (DELL T5400 standard config)

Comment: If you won't help us identify the performance bottleneck, what can we do for you. Given the code in the question how can you improve on what Remy wrote? You have to do more so that we can help.

Comment: The issue is 1 of 2: txtMailTo.Text := fMailTo.DelimitedText; takes to long time  or the update of control takes to long.  I have tried different controls and they all perform very slow,

Comment: We still don't know what that control is and how long the string is. I cannot fathom why you won't supply the mcve. Try to understand that all we know is that which can be found in this question.

Comment: I am sorry for the delay in answering - I have had someone take a look at the things here at my computer and we have found that the problem was a bit further away than thought of. It was the component retrieving tha data from db that slowed everything up.  We made changes in that and now everything is up to the speed wanted.

Comment: That's pretty much what I was driving at the whole time. There's no reason to believe that the code in your question would be a bottleneck.